# WebSphere - built-in memory profiler

Tags: websphere

I have tried some java profilers to profile WAS memory, but I guess due to the all SUN/IBM java thing, they don't support WAS.

Is there any built-in way to profile memory / analyze the heap dump a bit more / something in tracing and monitoring, perhepas?

If not, I know of some products - but the things is that we are in a closed enviornment - I can't just download and run. So if there is anything that comes with WAS, I would like to know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the HealthCenter

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/healthcenter/

It should be a reasonable one for you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any profiler that comes with WebSphere but you can download [IBM Support Assistant](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/isa/) (Free) and download the HeapAnalyzer which is very good for analyzing heap dumps.

Personally I did not try v5 yet but used the heap analyzer a lot.I

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in thing to do that, but IBM offers a graphical GC and Heap Analysing Tool. You will have to download it from IBM.

Please have a look here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/gcmv/

Answer (score 0):

The [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) can analyse both IBM and non-IBM heap dumps. It's also available in the IBM Support Assistant as a supported tool.